# Is it possible to assign django channels group in connection?

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

I hope you're all right:

my question is whether I can make a connection to web socket from the client to a specific group,
I'm currently connecting customers as follows:

```
//connecting client with js
var ws_scheme = window. location. protocol == "https:"? "wss":"ws";
//var ws_path = ws_scheme +': //' + window. location. host + "/sync/";
var ws_path = ws_scheme + ": //localhost: 8001";

console. log ("Connecting to " + ws_path);
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket (ws_path);
```

Okay, that's how it works,
The problem is that I want each client to connect to a group 
created previously example:

```
def ws_connect (message):
  for x in users:
    Group (x). add (message. reply_channel)
```

and so sent the message to the respective group

```
Group ("group1"). send ({' text': json. dumps (msg)})
Group ("group2"). send ({' text': json. dumps (msg)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while connecting to the sever pass the group name in url.

> wss://localhost:8001/sync/< groupname >/

and routing will be

```
route("websocket.connect", ws_connect, path=r"^/sync/(?P<group_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$")
```

and in consumers.py

```
def ws_connect(message, group_name):
    Group(group_name).add(message.reply_channel)
```